# Can the Acceptance rate for Metropolis-Hastings be greater than 1?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings

Can the acceptance rate in MH algo be greater than 1? When that case occurs the  proposal will off coruse be accepted with probability 1. But is it "ok" to allow a acceptance rate greater than 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It all depends what you mean by ["acceptance rate"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/271981/7224). If this means the ratio $$\dfrac{\pi(\theta^\text{prop})}{\pi(\theta^\text{current})}\times \dfrac{q(\theta^\text{current}|\theta^\text{prop})}{q(\theta^\text{prop}|\theta^\text{current})}$$appearing in the Metropolis-Hastings acceptance probability$$\min\left\{1,\dfrac{\pi(\theta^\text{prop})}{\pi(\theta^\text{current})}\times \dfrac{q(\theta^\text{current}|\theta^\text{prop})}{q(\theta^\text{prop}|\theta^\text{current})}\right\}$$then indeed this ratio can be larger than one, turning the acceptance probability into a value of $1$, meaning a sure jump from $\theta^\text{current}$ to $\theta^\text{prop}$. The validation of a Metropolis-Hastings move by detailed balance is based on this acceptance probability and the fact that it is sometimes equal to one is not an impediment to this validation.